# Error in shiro configuration in a Grails-app

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, shiro

i'm using the Apache Shiro as the framework for athetication of my application. I was following the reference at http://www.grails.org/plugin/shiro
and my application throws the exception:

**No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton. This is an invalid application configuration.**

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton. This is an invalid application configuration.
at org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager(SecurityUtils.java:115)
at org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.getSubject(SecurityUtils.java:57)
at br.netsoft.ShiroDbRealmTests.testAutenticarComDadosCorretos(ShiroDbRealmTests.groovy:58)
at junit.framework.Test$run.call(Unknown Source)

What i can do?

Comment: Are you only having the problem when running your tests? I'm using shiro also and I have this problem too - but only when testing. Have you worked out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue - see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-1980, there are a few suggested workarounds there.   Also, [this thread](http://n2.nabble.com/Issue-with-Grails-Shiro-td4568683.html#a4568683) sheds some light on potential cause.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this exception in unit test framework for grails app.
 I initialized the security service in setUp method and test test-framework no more getting this exception

```
@Before
void setUP(){
 new org.apache.shiro.grails.ShiroSecurityService()
}
```